# How to plot precision recall curves using .csv values?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the values of precision and recall at every epoch in .csv format? Now, I want to plot this values in form of precision_recall curve.

I mean precision on Y-axis and Recall on X-axis.

How can I visualise it in python3?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/roc-curves-and-precision-recall-curves-for-classification-in-python/ might also be interesting

Comment: Is your question still open?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your file is named 'my_precision_recall.csv' and looks like:

```
Recall,Precision
0.836,0.4672
0.8501,0.4447
...
```

You could plot your curve with 'Recall' as x-axis and 'Precision' as y-axis:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('my_precision_recall.csv')
df.plot('Recall', 'Precision')
plt.show()
```